# Creating Methods for TextBox Validations

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this big project which I'm looking forward to work on. There will be a lot of forms with a lot of textboxes, and I don't want to write code in each of the forms. I want to create a class with Methods to validate those textboxes. I don't know how.

I want this methods to accept a textbox eg: `ValidateTextBoxForInt(textbox1)` and validate it.
I'm going to use this in this way :

```
return ValidateTextBoxForInt(textbox1, textbox2);
```

(there could me only 1 textbox, maybe 100textboxes...depends on how many textboxes there are that need to be validated for int.)

Can anyone refer me anything ? Help me with this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: what do you wanna make in your validation ? Check if TextBox.Text is integer ?

Comment: What is your validation condition?

Comment: If the textbox.text is int return true else false.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a custom form which inherits from a regular form. It will have some Validate event, which will trigger it to go through all contained TextBoxes, validate those and provide some help message to let user know about the errors.

When enumerating through TextBoxes, don't forget that Form.Controls is a tree, not a list, so you may need recursion or flatten this tree first, to account for TextBoxes inside panels, tab controls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a validator class and call it passing in a control which is a parent of all your `TextBox` controls, such as a Panel:

```
public class Validator
{
    public bool ValidateAsInt(Control control)
    {
        bool valid = true;

        if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            int outVal = 0;
            if (0 == int.TryParse(((TextBox)control).Text, outVal))
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }

        if (valid)
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
            {
                if (!ValidateAsInt(childControl))
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```